# Why do I see a delay when I call a Perl program with system()?

Tags: perl

Scenario 1:
I have one wrapper Perl script which uses another Perl module and invokes a function in that module.

Scenario 2:
Now I have the same wrapper script and the module is implemented as Perl script. Here, instead  of using module I am simply calling `system("perl anotherscript.pl")`.

Both do the same function, but I am seeing a little bit delay in the second scenario.

Why is it so? Is it expected or is it something to do with my code?

Comment: Creating another process (system() call) is pretty expensive. In the first scenario you do it once, in the second one twice (right?). Do you call system() in a loop perhaps?

Comment: i am using any loops here.. i called it only once..

Comment: What I mean with "In the first scenario you do it once, in the second one twice" is that you first create one process for the wrapper script (e.g. from the shell) and then create a second process with the call to system().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first situation, you have the overhead of the Perl interpreter. In the second, you have the overhead of *two* Perl interpreters. If you want the second approach, consider an alternate and little-used version of the `do` function (see [`perldoc -f do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html)):

```
do './anotherscript.pl'
```

If the Perl interpreter is designed at all well (and it probably is), this will probably run significantly faster than the second example, though I don't know how it will compare to the first one. If you want efficiency, *benchmark*.

EDIT: If you don't care about the (probably insignificant) performance difference between the two, I recommend you just *use a module*. It will make your code infinitely more useful, because while a script can only be re-used in one piece, modules can be re-used in as many separate pieces as you like.

Comment: use module and do '/path/to/file' do different things in general. Just want to make that clear!

Comment: @derobert - I think he knows that already, since he has working programs using each method. But definitely, they do quite different things.

Comment: i was not aware of "do" could do something other than do - while.. thanks for pointing me that out :)

Comment: @Anandan - Neither was I for quite a while. Perl's documentation, both online and via the `perldoc` program, is excellent.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a module and a script at the same time by creating [modulinos](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=24678).